# xCode 5.1 build crashes - SpriteBuilder

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios7.1, xcode5.1, spritebuilder

I recently updated xCode to 5.1. All of a sudden my (cocos2d) builds keep on crashing when publishing to my iPhone 5s (iOS 7.1). It works fine in the simulator (iOS 7.1).
I got a screenshot here: http://puu.sh/7rB8S.png

Also I got a bunch of warnings since I updated xCode to 5.1. 
Replace above with: "7rBfp.png" (due to lack of reputation...)

If you are willing to reproduce the problem, I followed this tutorial: https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/menus/
Once I added the MainScene background (and the button + methods) I was not able to build on my iPhone anymore.

Am I missing something? Before I updated xCode and my phone today everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: It seems to be a 64bit bug:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/cocos2d-v3-cccontrol-crash-loading-spritebuilder-scene/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update Cocos2D, download the latest version ( https://s3.amazonaws.com/spritebuilder/cocos2d-iphone-3.0.0.rc.4.zip24 ), unzip the file and rename it to cocos2d-iphone and replace the version in your current project. It's in Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone.

Credits to Vic at the [SpriteBuilder forums](http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/new-xcode-5-1-crash/593/17) for this answer.