# XCode 5.1 force 32 bit compilation for a Cocos2d-iphone v3 project

Tags: ios, xcode, spritebuilder

I am using `SpriteBuilder`with Cocos2d-iphone v3.

Ever since updating to XCode 5.1 my application crashes when I use `CCButton` actions defined directly in `SpriteBuilder`. This seems to be the cause

> This is most likely a cast or pointer conversion, going bad on 64 bit.

as pointed out by @birkemose at the [Cocos2d forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/cocos2d-v3-cccontrol-crash-loading-spritebuilder-scene/)

How can I force XCode 5.1 to compile my project in **32 bit** even for my 64 bit devices?

### Update: Fix by updating Cocos2d to RC4

[xCode 5.1 build crashes - SpriteBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334250/xcode-5-1-build-crashes-spritebuilder)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your project's build settings, change Architectures from "Standard architectures" to "armv7, armv7s" (without the quotes).

Or as matt pointed out, you can use $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) instead, which is arguably the better way to go. Thanks matt!

Comment: Actually it would be better to put `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` rather than hard-coding those two specific architectures.

Comment: So I would have to do this in the target or the application or both?

Comment: I get a lot of linker errors for Chipmunk if I do it in the target, and the application still crashes from `CCButton` block if only the app build settings are set like so [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/FIetPlH.png)

Comment: Actually it does work. But you can't force 32 bit compilation and then say that build only for current device on debug if it is a 64 bit device.