# [Cocos2d][IOS]: cclabelttf shows up in top vertical alignment not center vertical alignment 64 bit

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I use a cclabelttf label to display text inside standard sprite images.
It works fine in retina and non-retina, but the last line of the text gets cut-off sometimes in 
the 64 bit iPad air.

This was the code I used,

```
[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:text fontName:_font fontSize:_fontSize dimensions:dimensions hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentCenter vAlignment:kCCVerticalTextAlignmentCenter lineBreakMode:kCCLineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

But when I changed the text to vertically align top, it started working again.

```
[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:text fontName:_font fontSize:_fontSize dimensions:dimensions hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentCenter vAlignment:kCCVerticalTextAlignmentTop lineBreakMode:kCCLineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Any idea what's going on ? I'd really like to have the center vertical align for my text.
Any solution to make that happen ?

Comment: v2.x? Are you building the arm64 slice? If so, don't, cocos2d v2.x is not 64-bit compatible. In any case make sure all 32-64 bit conversion warnings are on and check them thoroughly.

Comment: Yes, I am using cocos2d (2.1). And I am building the arm64 slice.
I thought it was mandatory from apple to have optimized apps for 64 bit versions.
I am using cocoapods to include cocos2d and the latest version automatically have the pod architecture to include arm64

Comment: Also I am using newline characters for multi-line rendering

Comment: OK, so I had to make my app 32 bit in the end.
Another option might have been, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363266/xcode-5-1-force-32-bit-compilation-for-a-cocos2d-iphone-v3-project

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this issue was similar to the cocos2dx version issue covered on this [link](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc/issues/672). You have to round up the CGSize components using the ceilf();

open up the CCTexture2d.m and find this method;

```
- (id) initWithString:(NSString*)string fontName:(NSString*)name fontSize:(CGFloat)size
```

and add the following code;

```
dim.width = ceilf(dim.width);
dim.height = ceilf(dim.height);
```

right after;

```
dim = [string sizeWithFont:font
             constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```