# Spritebuilder, XCode 5.1 and Device Build Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I just updated my Cocos2D to the newest version. I am using xcode 5.1 and am also using Spritebuilder. After updating my xcode I have been having a slew of errors and problems with my application. It's quite frustrating, because before I updated, I wasn't having any issues whatsoever.

I currently am testing my app on the iPhone 5S and iPhone 4S. It builds and runs on the 5S fine, but it has some UI issues, such as the titles of some of my buttons not showing up, and some CCLabels not appearing.

When I try to build and run on the iPhone 4S, I get this huge error, that I can't make any sense of:

```
file '/Users/Mikey/Desktop/MissileMadness.spritebuilder/Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d-    ui/CCBReader/CCBLocalizationManager.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/Mikey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MissileMadness-erzxydvceuwigkcfbtejuhnghdcf/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-cgfsucpxydgzhugfgfecjbxgjlks/Prefix.pch.pch' was built
```

Has anyone ever encountered this? I going crazy because I'm about done with my app and wanted to submit it soon.

Comment: do a clean (build folder), via xcode project menu

Comment: Updating to RC4 should fix the problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334250/xcode-5-1-build-crashes-spritebuilder

Comment: @TiborUdvari I actually got this error after upgrading.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I did that already, and I'm still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Oh, delete your derived data from your XCode.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you have an error with a `.pch` file.

PCH files can dramatically speed up your build process because they are built and cached. 
They are not very effective if you change the headers that are included in these things. Usually you would only put headers that do not change.

When updating Cocos for example, XCode may want to use the cached file, which is no longer correct so perform a **Project->Clean** and then delete your **Derived data** folder as outiled in the answer of the question below.

[Can I safely delete contents of Xcode Derived data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder)

Comment: I have the same problem and now I have fixed this issue by deleting the Derived data folder's content including Module Cache and after compiling derived data is generated automatically and linker error just magicaly removed.