# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when running Cocos2D V3 RC3 on iOS 7.1 device

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios7.1

I've recently discovered Cocos2D V3 with Chipmunk physics engine built right into it. There's only one template to create a project from. When I run the sample game on my iPod touch with iOS 6.1 it works as expected but when I run it on an iOS 7.1 device, like 5S or 5, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I click the [Newton physics] button. There's nothing else. It just shows EXC_BAD_ACCESS before the onNewtonClicked method, so it's not inside the method, but outside. Has someone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 32/64 bit compilation problem from Cocos2d.

You can fix this by updating to the latest RC 0.4 version.

Please check the instructions here to see how to do that : 
[xCode 5.1 build crashes - SpriteBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334250/xcode-5-1-build-crashes-spritebuilder/22389524#22389524)